# Comparing two Measures in single column using Table type visualization in power BI desktop

Tags: powerbi

I have two different data set for a category And I would like to compare both values using bars in table format.
I have achieved this in table type visual using conditional formatting data bars. With this option I have made a comparison by applying the conditional formatting in separate column (refer 1st image). But I would like to compare the two measures in single column (refer 2nd image).  Anyways to do that? Thanks  in advance.

Image 1:

[image: Image 1]

Image 2 ( Required ):

[image: Image 2 ( Required )]

Answer (score 0):

Not doable using `Table` visualization but you can achieve similar results using custom visuals like [bullet chart](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380755?tab=Overview).

Visualizations -> Import from store:

[image: import from store]

Search for bullet chart and add:

[image: search for bullet chart]

Set `Value` and `Target Value` with the two measures you have:

[image: bullet chart]

Comment: thanks @Foxan Ng . Is there anyway to do it with new custom visuals Table sorter type. I have tried it but only stocked column chart is available with that one.

Comment: @mani3593 I'm afraid the bullet chart is the closest you can get. You can write your own [custom visuals](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-custom-visuals-getting-started-with-developer-tools/) if it doesn't address your need.